# cvxpy solvers produce solutions of different shapes?

Tags: python, cvxpy, scs

I am trying to use [maxrect](https://github.com/planetlabs/maxrect)'s `get_maximal_rectangle`, which uses [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) under the hood.

With the [shapely](https://github.com/shapely/shapely) polygon:  POLYGON ((0 0.95, 0 2, 2 2, 2 1.95, 0 0.95))

```py
max_hull = shapely.wkt.loads('POLYGON ((0 0.95, 0 2, 2 2, 2 1.95, 0 0.95))') # this is a sample of a dynamically generated valid, simple, convex polygon
max_rect = get_maximal_rectangle(max_hull.exterior.coords[:-1])
print('max rectangle', max_rect)
```

this produces the error

> Either candidate conic solvers (['CVXOPT']) do not support the cones output by the problem (ExpCone, NonNeg, Zero), or there are not enough constraints in the problem.

so I checked maxrect's github issues. someone else reported the same problem. they solved it by modifying the call to cvx solve. So, I downloaded the source and modified the call to solve: `prob.solve(solver=cvxpy.CVXOPT, verbose=False, max_iters=1000, reltol=1e-9)` to just call it empty at first `prob.solve()`, but that produces

> Solver 'ECOS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.

(and verbose gives me no additional detail after "Invoking solver ECOS    to obtain a solution")

so I thought to use SCS. It works, actually, but here the solution values don't have the right shape(!?). the `get_maximal_rectangle` function wants to `return list(bottom_left[0]), list(top_right[0])`, but this raises

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

if I print  bottom left and top_right I see 4 values:

> [-3.86442831e+01 -2.49322910e+06] [ 8.14325412e+02 -2.03083800e+06]

but its hard to treat these as coordinates because 1. they are negative, so they are not inscribed in my polygon, and 2. it seems like the solver should return the same shape as CVXOPT.

Comment: Given that the maxrect repository was last updated 7 years ago and both numpy and cvxpy have moved on a lot since then I would expect weird incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found success in customizing this library for modern use.

```py
    prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, constraints)
    #prob.solve(solver=cvxpy.CVXOPT, verbose=False, max_iters=1000, reltol=1e-9)
    prob.solve()

    bottom_left = np.array(bl.value).T * scale
    top_right = np.array(tr.value).T * scale
    
    #return list(bottom_left[0]), list(top_right[0])
    return bottom_left, top_right
```

to convert the results back into a shapely object:

```py
    pa = get_maximal_rectangle(maximum_plot.exterior.coords)
    return Polygon([(pa[0][0],pa[0][1]), (pa[0][0],pa[1][1]), (pa[1][0],pa[1][1]), (pa[1][0],pa[0][1])])
```